# Select values from a grouped by set

Tags: mysql, sql

How can I make this [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d32c1/1) get results from the subset of elements returned by GROUP BY?

**Table**

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `accounts` (
  `master_id` int(3) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `child_id` int(3) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(200) NOT NULL
);
```

**Data**

```
INSERT INTO `accounts` (`master_id`, `child_id`, `name`) VALUES
  ('222', '555', 'child_555'),
  ('111', '111', 'master_111'),
  ('111', '999', 'child_999'),
  ('111', '888', 'child_888'),
  ('222', '222', 'master_222'),
  ('222', '777', 'child_777'),
  ('111', '666', 'child_666');
```

**Current query**

```
SELECT 
master_id, 
name, 
count(*) as "Total Accounts"
FROM `accounts`
GROUP BY master_id ASC;
```

**Results**

```
+-----------+------------+-------+
| master_id |    name    | Total |
+-----------+------------+-------+
|       111 | master_111 |     4 |
|       222 | child_555  |     3 |
+-----------+------------+-------+
```

**Expected**

```
 - Don't count child if child_id == master_id
 - Get correct name

+-----------+------------+-------+
| master_id |    name    | Total |
+-----------+------------+-------+
|       111 | master_111 |     3 |
|       222 | master_222 |     2 |
+-----------+------------+-------+
```

Comment: In according to table structure and logic each master row has the same master_id and child_id so `count(*) - 1` will work.

Comment: Try with WHERE master_id <> child_id in the where clause

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think a simple aggregation with some conditional logic is the best approach:

```
SELECT master_id,
       MAX(CASE WHEN child_id = master_id THEN name END) as name,
       SUM(child_id <> master_id) as "Total Accounts"
FROM `accounts`
GROUP BY master_id ASC;
```

[Here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d32c1/54) is the SQL Fiddle for this.

Comment: This is an elegant query :) Is there any performance to gain compared to the other solutions (join, commas in FROM)?

Comment: @numediaweb . . . The other solutions use `group by` as well, so I would not expect the performance to be better.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT 
b.master_id, 
a.name,
count(*) as "Total Accounts"
FROM accounts b, accounts a
where b.master_id<>b.child_id
and a.child_id = b.master_id
GROUP BY b.master_id ASC;
```

or as M Khalid Junaid suggested:

```
SELECT 
  b.master_id,
  a.name,
  COUNT(*) AS "Total Accounts" 
FROM
  accounts b 
  JOIN accounts a 
    ON b.master_id <> b.child_id 
    AND a.child_id = b.master_id 
GROUP BY b.master_id ASC
```

Result:

```
master_id   name        Total Accounts
111         master_111  3
222         master_222  2
```

Comment: @MKhalidJunaid your comment works: can you please make it as answer so i can accept it

Comment: @numediaweb i have created demo using **Mark**'s answer if it satisfies your needs you can accept his answer

Comment: I used the JOIN variation as it is faster

Comment: Why would anyone upvote an answer that uses commas in the `FROM` clause?  Especially when a join is not needed for the logic.

Answer (score 1):

Use `case` expression to do *conditional* aggregation :

```
select b.master_id, a.name, 
       sum(case when b.master_id <> b.child_id then 1 else 0 end) as "Total Accounts"
from `accounts` a
inner join `accounts` b on a.child_id = b.master_id
group by b.master_id 
order by b.master_id ASC;
```

However, `WHERE` clause should also do the work.

```
select master_id, name, 
       count(*) as "Total Accounts"
from `accounts`
where master_id != child_id
group by master_id 
order by master_id ASC;
```

Comment: Not working: it doesn't get correct name for master 222

Comment: @numediaweb. . . Do the `JOIN` which i missed.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution without self-join

```
SELECT 
  `master_id`, 
  max(case when `master_id` = `child_id` then `name` end) n,
  count(case when `master_id` != `child_id` then 1 end) as "Total Accounts"
FROM `accounts` a1
GROUP BY master_id ASC;
```

[DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.2&fiddle=a38a8217250ce170a888f7ba1e785e28)

Comment: But I need name as well

Answer (score 0):

```
select master_id, name, 
       sum(master_id != child_id) as Total
from `accounts`
group by master_id 
order by master_id ASC;
```

[Demo on SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/2a65d/2)

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
SELECT master_id, name, count(*) as "Total Accounts" 
FROM accounts where master_id != child_id
GROUP BY master_id ASC;
```